# Quotation-Marks causing IllegalNameException when parsing HTML with JDom2

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jdom

Good Evening everyone!

I'm trying to parse a HTML-page in Java with JDOM2, to access some information from it.

My code looks like this: (Just added the packages for this codeblock, don't have them in my real source)

```
//Here goes the reading of the site into my String "string" (using NekoHTML)

org.xml.sax.InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(string));

org.cyberneko.html.parsers.DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
parser.parse(is);

org.jdom2.input.DOMBuilder builder = new DOMBuilder();
org.jdom2.Document doc = builder.build(parser.getDocument());
```

This works fine for everything except some special case: When the site contains quotation-Marks within an element. Here is an example of what I mean:

`<a href="LINK" title="Der "realismo mágico" und die Phantastische Literatur">Der "realismo mágico" und die Phantastische...</a>`

So, after that wonderful Tag I get the following error-trace:

`SEVERE: org.jdom2.IllegalNameException: The name "literatur"" is not legal for JDOM/XML attributes: XML name 'literatur"' cannot contain the character """.`

So, now my question is: What are my options to take care of this error? Is there maybe a feature in NekoHTML I can use for this (using the "setFeature()"), or something within JDOM I could use?

If no: Are there other libaries that are suitable for scraping websites that can take such a thing as the quotation mark within the tag?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The HTML is not valid. There is a problem with the value of the title attribute.

Comment: What Henry says. The DOM you are trying to give to JDOM is not valid. It essentially has something that, in 'real' XML, would look like: `literatur"=""` which is obviously not right. It is trying to tell JDOM that the name of the attribute (not the value) is `literatur"`

Comment: Well, I assumed that it is not right, but that is the site as I scrape it.
Is there no way to change it? Without going through the whole page maybe? Or just using another parser for it maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I solved the problem like following:

Since there wasn't any dependency on NekoHTML I switched to [jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) as parser which does the job in this case.

Question answered.